# How can I control each blend shape value from a script using the blend shape name not by index?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For example I want to change the mouth blend shape value from 0 to 23 randomly to simulate talking when I'm showing text. It's no really the lips will move like the text it's just to simulate talking when the text show so I want to make something more or less randomly values between 0 and 23.

[image: Blend Shapes]

I tried this but it's not working it does nothing. It's not changing the mouse blendshape value at all.

The scripts is attached to the object with the blendshapes.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BlendShapesController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SkinnedMeshRenderer bodySkinnedMeshRenderer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bodySkinnedMeshRenderer = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int rand = Random.Range(0, 23);
        bodySkinnedMeshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight(0, rand);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution : Since the object with the SkinnedMeshRenderer is a child and the parent have a Animator component I had to change the Animator component settings on the parent object to Animate Physics and Always Animate.

I'm using by index not by name but it's working so I will consider it for the meanwhile as a solution since it's working.

Comment: God, without your post, there is no way I can find the solution to this. Great answer! I have no idea what is Animator's 'Animate Physics', but it is updating the mesh!